# Hashes do not work because of what appears to be a time delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I have a domain where I can navigate to as follow:

```
mydomain.com
```

and the page loads fine.  From there I can add hashes to access parts of the page as follows:

```
mydomain.com#some_place
```

This appears to work b.c. the page is already fully loaded.

However if I copy paste the whole domain and hash into the URL and hit enter

```
mydomain.com#some_place
```

It will not go to `some_place` but just loads as if the hash was not even there.

How can I troubleshoot further?

Comment: Is there a way I can read the hash programmatically and then programaically have the page scroll once the DOM has finished loading perhaps ?

Comment: Shouldn't the browser know not to look for the hash until the page has loaded? WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once all your components have mount use the built in `componentDidMount` life cycle method along with

```
  this.useScrollTo(element);
```

where us `this.useScrollTo` is defined below

```
  useScrollTo(element) {
    const elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const offsetPosition = elementPosition - 80;
    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetPosition,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your useEffect hook, redirect your page to `document.location.href`, which is your URL with hash.

Also `document.location.hash` gives you your hash.

Edit: 
Here is an updated, tested solution:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (document.location.hash) {
      const hashElement = document.querySelector(document.location.hash);
      hashElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: I don't know to be honest. Here is another solution I just figured: 
```const hashElement = document.querySelector(document.location.hash);
hasElement.scrollIntoView();
```
Apparently this one does not do any refresh. Just use it in your useEffect or componentDidMount

Comment: I will test it give me a second

Comment: Try this, it worked on my code. It jumps to the #hash link, you must have an element in the HTML with id="hash" to work.
`useEffect(() => {
    if (document.location.hash) {
      const hashElement = document.querySelector(document.location.hash);
      hashElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }, []);
`

Comment: `componentDidMount` is for class components, `useEffect` is for function components. You don't need it, it's just the way you handle side effects in function components. If you have class components, you have to use `componentDidMount` anyways. Also I tested my solution but have no idea why it would throw an error. Eventually, `querySelector` and `getElementById` can perform the same job, it's just a subtle use difference. I'm glad it worked for you 

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hash and then scroll the page to the element using:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = window.location.hash
    const elem = document.getElementById(url)
    elem.scrollIntoView()
}, [])
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: location.hash would give you `#hash` but `getElementById` accepts only `hash`, this would work if you use `querySelector` instead of  `getElementById`